# Show left navigation/quick launch in sharepoint 2013 master page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have created a custom master page. Now the problem is that it is not showing the left side nav box / quick launch bar which is active in case of built in master pages like seattle.

Wanted to know how to add this left side navigation bar to master page.

Edit:
Also added following from OSLO but nothing happens

```
<div id="sideNavBox" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList">
<a id="startNavigation" name="startNavigation" tabIndex="-1"></a>
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar" Visible="true" class="ms-core-navigation ms-belltown-sideNavDelta" BlockElement="true" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" Visible="true" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarTop" Visible="true" runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchTop" Visible="true" runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarDataSource" Visible="true" runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator" Visible="true" runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftActions" Visible="true" runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom" Visible="true" runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you have created your master page, but if you're not sure what needs to be included in your custom master page for all standard sharepoint functionality to work, it's best to start with one of the [Starter Master Pages](https://startermasterpages.codeplex.com) from codeplex. These are clean and well commented.

To add quick launch make sure to include following code in your master page:

```
            <SharePoint:SPNavigationManager
                id="QuickLaunchNavigationManager"
                runat="server"
                QuickLaunchControlId="V4QuickLaunchMenu"
                ContainedControl="QuickLaunch"
                EnableViewState="false"
                >
                <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server"
                    ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource">
                    <Template_Controls>
                        <asp:SiteMapDataSource
                            SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
                            ShowStartingNode="False"
                            id="QuickLaunchSiteMap"
                            StartingNodeUrl="sid:1025"
                            runat="server"
                        />
                    </Template_Controls>
                </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
                <SharePoint:AspMenu
                    id="V4QuickLaunchMenu"
                    runat="server"
                    EnableViewState="false"
                    DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap"
                    UseSimpleRendering="true"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    StaticDisplayLevels="3"
                    AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
                    MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0"
                    SkipLinkText=""
                />
            </SharePoint:SPNavigationManager>
```

Comment: when i add this to my master html page, it says that this page has a component and it needs to be renamed to .aspx? When i did that, it was only an fatal error message, nothing appears.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update how I fixed it. I used Seattler master page HTML and then used it as the base of my custom master page. Few design adjustments and it works.